# Does Windows Server 2012 supports IIS 10 Express?

Tags: iis-express, windows-server-2012, iis-10

I am planning to get VPS with Windows Server 2012, And they are providing IIS 8.5, and I want to make use of *.example.com kind of thing which is supported on IIS 10. 
So wanted to know does it supports or I can install the same on Windows server 2012.

Comment: FYI, ' *.example.com kind of thing' is called a Sub-domain :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIS 10 Express says it supports server 2012. Check System Requirements -> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48264

Comment: thats express, sorry for not being clear. I am updating your answer and will mark it correct answer